# Change encoding while writing a file

Tags: python

I am writing one file :

```
 with open("test_%s.tem" %i, "w") as f1:
 ....
 f1.close()
```

I want to convert the encoding to UCS-2 little endian format. Is it possible to do this in open() or close() functions. Any ideas would help.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488346/python-3-reading-ucs-2-be-file

Answer (score 2):

In `Python 3`,  according to documentation in :https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open
you can specify the encoding with the encoding parameter.

```
with open("test_%s.tem" %i, "w", encoding="utf16") as f1:
```

Comment: I am using python 2.7. I tried using codecs. However it shows:UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: ascii values should be between `1` to `128`. you are trying to write `239` (0xef)

Answer (score 1):

On Python 2 you can use [codecs.open](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) with the *encoding* parameter.

If you use Python 3 just use the *encoding* parameter of [open](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#open).

UCS-2 is a subset of UTF-16, so try to use `'UTF-16'` as the parameter value.