# Linux converting my URLs to at signs?

Tags: python, linux, debian

I have a script I've been developing on my mac that uses scrapy, a python library for web scraping. I thought everything was fine until I tried to load it onto the server this morning.

The server runs Debian 8.2 and it scrapes fine. The problem comes with reading its scraped file. Debian seems to read the file as a great number of at signs (`@n^@^@^@d^@^@^@e^@^@^@x^@^@^@.^@^@^@p`), but uploading the file to Dropbox and looking at it reveals that the file is in fact full of URLs. So the scraping is fine, but the file cannot be read properly.

How can I resolve this?

Larger slice:
`i^@^@^@n^@^@^@d^@^@^@e^@^@^@x^@^@^@.^@^@^@p^@^@^@h^@^@^@p^@^@^@i^@^@^@n^@^@^@d^@^@^@e^@^@^@x^@^@^@.^@^@^@p^@^@^@h^@^@^@p^@^@^@?^@^@^@s^@^@^@t^@^@^@r^@^@^@P^@^@^@a^@^@^@g^@^@^@e^@^@^@I^@^@^@D^@^@^@=^@^@^@S^@^@^@F^@^@^@0^@^@^@1^@^@^@_^@^@^@0^@^@^@3^@^@^@_^@^@^@0^@^@^@1^@^@^@.^@^@^@.^@^@^@/^@^@^@k^@^@^@o^@^@^@/^@^@^@.^@^@^@.^@^@^@/^@^@^@e^@^@^@n^@^@^@/^@^@^@.^@^@^@.^@^@^@/^@^@^@c^@^@^@n^@^@^@/^@^@^@i^@^@^@n^@^@^@d^@^@^@e^@^@^@x^@^@^@.^@^@^@p^@^@^@h^@^@^@p^@^@^@?`

Comment: what are you using to read the file on the local machine?

Comment: Could this be an artifact due to the setting of the LANG system variable?

Comment: I used nano to just take a look at it, but technically the script uses sed.

Comment: Can you post a hex-dump of the first 24 or so characters? I have a hunch that it's being stored in full UCS-4 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32).

Comment: Definitely looks like UCS-4.

Comment: I've added a little more, if it were UCS-4, what would be the way of resolving this?

Comment: Have not tested, but try `iconv -f UCS-4 -t UTF-8 infile > outfile`

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a problem with UCS-2 (which is, basically, UTF-16). Use `encoding='utf16'` or `encoding='utf_16_be'` encoding in you python program (see details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488346/python-3-reading-ucs-2-be-file)).

You can convert your files from UCS-2 to UTF-8 using `iconv` utility this way:

```
iconv -f UCS-2 -t UTF-8 inputfile > outputfile
```