# unable to decode this string using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this text.ucs file which I am trying to decode using python.

```
file = open('text.ucs', 'r')
content = file.read()
print content
```

My result is

\xf\xe\x002\22

I tried doing decoding with utf-16, utf-8

```
content.decode('utf-16')
```

and getting error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_16.py", line 16, in
>   decode
>       return codecs.utf_16_decode(input, errors, True) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode bytes in position
>   32-33: illegal encoding

Please let me know if I am missing anything or my approach is wrong

Edit: Screenshot has been asked 
[image]

Comment: @Rakesh Sorry, can't post that here

Comment: Where do you get `text.ucs` from?

Comment: Do you know what alphabet it's supposed to be?

Comment: This is having load balancer information

Comment: Try `encoding='utf_16_be'` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14488478/1388292)

Comment: @JacquesGaudin I tried all the existing solution from stackoverflow but none is working so posted here

Answer (score 1):

The string is encoded as UTF16-BE (Big Endian), this works:

```
content.decode("utf-16-be")
```

Comment: @JacquesGaudin unfortunately both are not working but as per python docs, i see '-' and not '_'

Comment: @cyborg I executed this on the bytes that you provided just now, worked fine. The names with dashes and underscores are equivalent, first paragraph of https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Comment: >>> content.decode("utf_16_be")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_16_be.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_16_be_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode byte 0x5c in position 64: truncat
ed data

Answer (score 1):

oooh, as i understand you using python 2.x.x but encoding parameter was added only in python 3.x.x as I know, i am doesn't master of python 2.x.x but you can search in google about io.open for example try:

```
file = io.open('text.usc', 'r',encoding='utf-8')
content = file.read()
print content
```

but chek do you need import io module or not

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which encoding to use with the `encoding` argument:

```
with open('text.ucs', 'r', encoding='utf-16') as f:
    text = f.read()
```

Comment: the error message I got: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: maybe you forgotten that if you usin `with open()` you need to set name for this for example : `with open('text.ucs', 'r', encoding='utf-16') as file`

Comment: I did it, I am aware of with usage :)

Comment: really i don't know why it's doesn't work, i tested it 20 secs ago and this construction haven't any errors my full code is `with open(source, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:`...

Comment: I have added screenshot in question, please check

Answer (score 0):

your string need to Be Uncoded With The Coding utf-8 you can do What I Did Now for decode your string

```
f = open('text.usc', 'r',encoding='utf-8')
print f
```

Comment: A few words to explain why you think this fixes the OP issue would be a good idea. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @JacquesGaudin thanks for that i will be more attentive about my answer next time