# How change unicode language of dumpdata in .json format

Tags: python, django

I created dumpdata but when i try to load this by using command:

```
py manage.py loaddata backup.json
```

Then i have error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Then when i opened this database by Notepad then it shown me that its encoded in UCS-2 LE BOM, how I can save dumpdata in UTF-8 language?

Comment: Decoding in utf-16 could be worth a try, see details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488346/python-3-reading-ucs-2-be-file

Answer (score 0):

Edit your backup.json using Notepad ++ (in Windows right-click the file and Notepad ++ should be an option) and under the Encoding drop down select 'Encode in UTF-8'. This will change the encoding and allow you to load your fixture.